# Php login script not working on newer server

Tags: php

I moved a login php script from a pretty old server to a newer server. All settings and chmods are put the same but the php script does not work on the newer server.  When entering the correct login and password it does not go to main.php but stays on the index.php login page and adds this message "Invalid Username or Password!'; } } ?>".

I am a programming noob but perhaps the script uses certain coding that is better  not used anymore at newer servers. Any ideas what to change to the script so it could possible work again? Thank you in advance.

Here is the code of the index.php login page:

```
<?
ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
session_start();

$username = "admin";
$password = "admin";

// main page
$mainpage = "main.php";

if(isset($_SESSION['logedin']))
if($_SESSION['logedin'] == 'loggedin')
{
header("Location: $mainpage");
exit(); 
}

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

if($_POST['username'] == $username && $_POST['password'] == $password)
{
        $_SESSION['logedin'] = 'loggedin';

        // Redirect to the page
        header("Location: $mainpage");
        exit();
}
else
{
        $error = '<br /><br />Invalid Username or Password!';
}
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en-US">
<head>
<title>test</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8" />
<style type="text/css">
html, body, #wrapper {
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
#wrapper td {
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
#headerBox {
    border: 1px solid #A6E0FF;
    width: 800px;
    color: #00529B;
    background: #EDF8FE;
    height: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
#top {
    color: #00529B;
    background: #DAF3FF;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #BFE9FF;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    font-weight:bold;

}
#bottom {
    color: #00529B;
    background: #EDF8FE;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 30px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table id="wrapper">
<tr>
<td>
<div id="headerBox">
<form method="post" id="login" action="index.php">
<div id="top">Log In</div>
<div id="bottom">
Username: <input id="username" name="username" type="text" />
Password: <input id="password" name="password" type="password" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Log in" />
<? if(isset($error)) echo $error; ?>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
<!--
document.getElementById("username").focus();
//-->
//]]>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try using `<?php` instead of `<?`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seemed to be missing an opening bracket after an if-statement, so this should be working:

```
<?php

ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
session_start();

$username = "admin";
$password = "admin";

// main page
$mainpage = "main.php";

if(isset($_SESSION['logedin']))
{
  if($_SESSION['logedin'] == 'loggedin')
  {
    header("Location: $mainpage");
    exit(); 
  }
}

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

  if($_POST['username'] == $username && $_POST['password'] == $password)
  {
    $_SESSION['logedin'] = 'loggedin';

    // Redirect to the page
    header("Location: $mainpage");
    exit();
  }
  else
  {
    $error = '<br /><br />Invalid Username or Password!';
  }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en-US">
<head>
<title>test</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8" />
<style type="text/css">
html, body, #wrapper {
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
#wrapper td {
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
#headerBox {
    border: 1px solid #A6E0FF;
    width: 800px;
    color: #00529B;
    background: #EDF8FE;
    height: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
#top {
    color: #00529B;
    background: #DAF3FF;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #BFE9FF;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    font-weight:bold;    

}
#bottom {
    color: #00529B;
    background: #EDF8FE;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 30px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table id="wrapper">
<tr>
<td>
<div id="headerBox">
<form method="post" id="login" action="index.php">
<div id="top">Log In</div>
<div id="bottom">
Username: <input id="username" name="username" type="text" />
Password: <input id="password" name="password" type="password" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Log in" />
<?php if(isset($error)) { echo $error; } ?>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
<!--
document.getElementById("username").focus();
//-->
//]]>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```